# How do I debug m2e lifecyclemapping?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm trying to configure a lifecycle mapping but I can't tell what m2e is doing since nothing appears in workspace/.metadata/.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each plugin can control log data individually.

- Locate the plugin config inside the workspace (.e.g, .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback..xml
- modify the root logger (or add your additional loggers using the standard logging approach - easiest is to change INFO to DEBUG)
- Restart eclipse
- monitor log file (e.g., .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/0.log)

Now that you can see what's going on, you can get the source of plugins with invoked executions and work to understand what's skipped and why.